# QGIS import several text files

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, import

I tried to import several text files using the Python console, but I failed.

This is the code I used:

```py
import os.path, glob
layers=[]
for file in glob.glob('E:/tmp/QGIS_CSVimport_test/*'):
uri = "file:///" + file + "?type=csv&xField=x&yField=y&spatialIndex=no&subsetIndex=no&watchFile=no&crs=epsg:32156"
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, os.path.basename(file), "delimitedtext")
vlayer.addAttributeAlias(0,'x')
vlayer.addAttributeAlias(1,'y')
layers.append(vlayer)

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers(layers)
```

[image: example of one txt-file]

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
import glob, os

layers = []
for file in glob.glob(r'/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/C*.csv'):
    print(file)
    uri = f"file://{file}?type=csv&xField=x&yField=y&zField=z&crs=EPSG:32156"
    vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, os.path.basename(file), "delimitedtext")
    vlayer.setFieldAlias(1,'XXX') #First (index 0) field is Nr, x is second
    vlayer.setFieldAlias(2,'YYY')
    layers.append(vlayer)

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayers(layers)
```

I usually add one csv manually Ctrl+Shift+T, go to layer properties, and copy the source string and use as uri template:

[image]